# Mechanics of surfing

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

Some time ago I was sitting by a river watching the water flow and some remarkable surfers in the river. After some time I realized that I could not really grasp the mechanics of what I was watching, so here I summarize the problem.

The current of the river was so strong that it carries you roughly ten meters in few seconds if you jump there.

To be able to surf, the surfers jump into the rivers with some initial impulse perpendicular to the current flow, and they surf back and forth along the width of the river, without going with the current at all (they stay at the same level along the river). They continue doing this until they slip and fall into the water. Once they fall, they are immediately carried away by the current, and so they get out of the river, come back walking to the initial jumping point and jump again.

The first obvious question for me was : What is the force acting on the surfer against the current to keep him fixed at the same $z$ level while he was surfing. This force disappears when the surfer falls, so it is not hydrostatic and must be hydrodynamic.

The second question came from the fact that I later tried to stand up on a (typical low volume) surf board myself and I could not stand on the board unless the board was moving. Here again I realized that by the physical properties of the board (density, volume..), it is not possible to be in hydrostatic equilibrium, so a hydrodynamic force must be pushing the surfer against gravity. This question is more difficult because the flow in $z$ direction is actually generating a force perpendicular to $z$ direction.

**My suggestion**

By looking closely at the river where surfers jump, one recognizes some sort of ramp below the water whose angle can be manually adjusted by the surfers. I think this ramp effectively tilts the surface of the water, thus making the gravity of the surfer act against the flow. So this could answer the first question.

For the second question I do not have yet an idea but I think this should not be specific to this case and should be more general about hydrodynamics of surfing, so I would try to read more about that.

[image]